# Want to initiate and manage a voice call from an android application

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager, dtmf

I want to initiate and manage a call from android, without any interaction with the default dialer. The call should automatically be initiated from the application, and the application should be able to send DTMF tones programatically, and also terminate the call programatically. The dialer should never come to foreground during this process.

I have seen many examples of initiating the call with an intent. Unfortunately, the call will be passed on to the dialer and the dialer will take control from then on. 
Here is one such example.
[Android: calling number without user init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696922/android-calling-number-without-user-init)

Is this possible? If not, it would help if you can point me to the documentation.

Comment: You state, "Unfortunately, the call will be passed on to the dialer and the dialer will take control from then on". Why is this an issue? Can you provide more details on the type of integration this application will need with the call once it is initiated?

Comment: This application is meant for customer support. The application will initiate the call, and while the user is talking to customer support, the agent will send text or images. This text or images should directly be displayed by the application while the call is in progress.